# If condition and Conditional column not working as expected in power query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

So I have a requirement if [condition1] = 'apple' and [condition2] = 'xx' then 'fruit' else if [condition2] = 'beans' and condition[2] = 'yy' then 'veggie' else [display all names as-is from another column]. can some one please help me how can we achieve this as conditional column is impacting performance and not helping as final else is not a specific field but instead all other rows in a column.

Comment: Add some sample data and your expected output from them to make the requirement clear. Your last 2 lines are really confusing. You wants the logic of if condition? or facing issue with the code you developed?

Comment: Also, specify if you are calculating it using DAX or M (PowerQuery) and if you are looking for a solution with just one of them